# Why can I not look up classes from sun.misc.DelegatingClassLoader

Tags: java, classloader

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29087102/1237575), I found that it is not possible to look up a class from a `sun.misc.DelegatingClassLoader`, i.e. looking up a class on its own class loader like

```
Class<?> accessor = ...
accessor.getClassLoader().findClass(accessor.getName());
```

throws a `ClassNotFoundException`. The delegating class loader is used for loading runtime-generated accessor classes for converting Java's reflective JNI calls into Java invocations.

For some strange reason, I am [not able to find the source of the `DelegatingClassLoader` anywhere in the JDK sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/reflect) even though it is clearly available in my build where it seems to be an empty implementation of a subclass of the standard `ClassLoader` from looking at the class's byte code.

If the `DelegatingClassLoader` is however really only a simple subclass, I do not understand why it is not possible to look up a class by its name. Is there some VM magic involved? It seems like the

```
private native final Class<?> findLoadedClass0(String name);
```

method does not return the loaded class for a `DelegatingClassLoader`. The private `classes` field does however include the loaded class.

I was not able to find any information on how these class loaders are supposed to be different from any other class loaders. I am looking for an explanation why the above lookup does not work but throws an exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for DelegatingClassLoader is for whatever reason located in [ClassDefiner.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/ClassDefiner.java).  Interestingly, this code has a comment that references [bug 4474172](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4474172), which suggests that this class loader is known to the JVM and has special behavior:

> The second solution is to make the virtual machine "magically"
>   delegate class loading for these newly-fabricated class loaders to
>   their parent loaders, without making an upcall to Java. The
>   disadvantage is that this is another hack in the JVM [...]. This
>   option has been chosen.